# Use count and group by in a joins table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, store

Here is my query and I want to add the "count of SalID group by OFID" and store the result in the same table.

```
SELECT
    T_OF.OFID,
    T_OF.OFDateDPrev, T_OF.OFDateFPrev,
    T_OF_User.OFUserID,
    T_OF_User.SalID
INTO T_tracing
FROM T_OF
INNER JOIN T_OF_User
    ON T_OF_User.OFID = T_OF.OFID
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT
    T_OF.OFID,
    T_OF.OFDateDPrev, T_OF.OFDateFPrev,
    T_OF_User.OFUserID,
    Count (SalID) FROM T_OF_User GROUP BY OFID
INTO T_tracing
FROM T_OF
INNER JOIN T_OF_User
    ON T_OF_User.OFID = T_OF.OFID
```

But I have an error message. Any help please?

Comment: Um, what is the error message?

Comment: `GROUP BY` goes after the `WHERE` and before the `HAVING`, in the end of the `SELECT`/`before the `INTO`. Also you have 2 `FROM` clauses in your query.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a window function:

```
SELECT T_OF.OFID, T_OF.OFDateDPrev, T_OF.OFDateFPrev, T_OF_User.OFUserID,
       Count(SalID) OVER (PARTITION BY T_OF.OFID) as cnt
INTO T_tracing
FROM T_OF JOIN
     T_OF_User
     ON T_OF_User.OFID = T_OF.OFID;
```

You also need to give the result of the expression a name for `T_Tracing`.